# PyPiServer debugging "could not find a version that satisfies the requirement"

Tags: python, pip, package, pypi

I'm creating a private package repository using PyPiServer. I'm serving this on one VPS instance and trying to pip install from another.

Traceback from pip:

```
root@managersvr:~# pip install --index-url http://<IP>:8080/simple/ global_toolkit --trusted-host <IP>
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement global_toolkit (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for global_toolkit
root@managersvr:~#
```

Server logs from PyPi:

```
[02/May/2020 23:57:10] "GET /simple/global-toolkit/ HTTP/1.1" 200 313
```

I'm struggling to debug. Steps taken so far:
 - I have run `pip install --upgrade pip`
 - I have navigated to the PyPi IP address in browser, which correctly displays:

```
Welcome to pypiserver!
This is a PyPI compatible package index serving 1 packages.

To use this server with pip, run the following command:

        pip install --index-url http://<IP>:8080/simple/ PACKAGE [PACKAGE2...]

To use this server with easy_install, run the following command:

        easy_install --index-url http://<IP>:8080/simple/ PACKAGE [PACKAGE2...]

The complete list of all packages can be found here or via the simple index.

This instance is running version 1.3.2 of the pypiserver software.
```

Navigating to the "here" link for a complete list of all packages yields:

```
Index of packages
global_toolkit.tar.gz
```

And navigating to the simple index yields:

```
Simple Index
global-toolkit
```

I also tried using global-toolkit instead of global_toolkit.

I am looking for steps to identify the layer at which there is an error, and debug it. Thanks.

UPDATE

I found the pip search command. The output is, strange:

```
(venv) root@managersvr:~# pip search --index http://<IP>:8080 global_toolkit
global_toolkit ()  -
```

Comment: Could it be that packages have to be of a particular format (e.g. .eggs)?

Comment: Possible. I'm following this tutorial though which specifies .tar.tz https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/project-management/how-to-create-a-private-python-package-repository/

Comment: You need to use the same name in the package as you use for the file I assume. (dash vs underscore)

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue. In hindsight I should have foreseen the problem. I failed to include my ext_modules value in the top level setup.py (so the cython modules weren't compiled). A good tip for debugging: use the -v flag!